# padding and color isn't defined

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Size size = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return Container(
      margin: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 10),
      width: size.width * 0.8,
      child: ClipRRect(
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(29),
        child: TextButton(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
            color: color,
            onPressed: (){
              Navigator.pushReplacement(
                context, 
                MaterialPageRoute(
                  builder: (co
``
                    return const HomePage();
                  },
```

Comment: [TextButton](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextButton-class.html) doesn't have `color` and `padding` properties

Comment: @Zero Two Welcome to SO :) For future questions, it's useful to add a bit of a description/context for the error your getting

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing TextButton with this code.

```
Container(
          color: Colors.teal,
          padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(vertical: 20, horizontal: 40),
          width: ${Size you want},
          height: ${Size you want},
          child: TextButton(
            onPressed: () {},
            child: Text('Try this.'),
          ),
        ),
```